# Add SQL Analysis Services to a existing SharePoint Farm

Tags: 2013, sql-server, sql-analysis-services, services

Our SharePoint Farm is based on a failover SQL cluster (MS SQL 2012 Standard). The problem is, that the Analysis Services were not installed with the database engine.

If I'm understanding right, it's not supported to add/remove any features to an existing failover cluster at all?

I need some ideas/options to get the Analysis Service available to the farm.

Answer (score 1):

Analysis services is a Completely different application than your clustered DB engine.  you can have clustered and non-clustered apps on the same server.  I don't recommend that, but its possible.  With PowerPivot you point at discrete installations tbat are neither load balanced nor clustered.

I personally would stand up a dedicated server/instance for analysis services if resources are available to support it.

Comment: could be the dedicated instance created on the same SQL cluster like the DB engine?

Comment: Yes - you can technically deploy clustered and non-clustered applications on the same box. the cluster is just a "service" and applications that are deployed to use that service.

Comment: hm ok, I'll try to add a additional instance with Analysis Services. Thanks !